# Drag and drop html dom elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `DOM` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
   <div>
     label <input id="field_input"> 
   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

When I put value to this field, for example: `hello`

[image]

then I want to highlight this `label - hello` element and drag and grop this element `label <input id="field_input">`  with inserted value `hello` to somewhere. 
Somewhere this is the second question
Please help me out.

> Please no `HTML5` solutions.

Comment: Sorry DRAG insted drug

Comment: Lay off the drugs and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863998/simple-javascript-drag-and-drop-witout-the-help-of-a-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585571/drag-and-drop-feature-in-javascript

Comment: Do you mean the user should be able drag and drop it or that the code should move the label to a different part of the HTML page?